# addTemplate() gives UndeterministicSelectionException

Tags: weblogic, weblogic11g, wlst

We have 3 weblogic extension templates jars A,B and C. We have created another template jar D which deploys all the three templates by specifying their names under dependency tag in template-info.xml as shown below.

template-info.xml

```
<dependency>
    <and>
      <requires name="A" version="11.1.1.0" colocated="false" />
      <requires name="B" version="11.1.1.0" colocated="false" />
      <requires name="C" version="11.1.1.0" colocated="false" />
    </and>
  </dependency>
```

If D template is applied for a new empty domain with addTemplate it deploys all the templates successfully. But the same template fails for custom domain(domain with managed server and few data sources) with the below error message. Please help.

```
wls:/offline/CustomDomain>addTemplate('/scratch/D.jar')


Error: addTemplate() failed. Do dumpStack() to see details.
wls:/offline/CustomDomain>wls:/offline/CustomDomain>dumpStack()
com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLSTException: com.oracle.cie.domain.script.ScriptException: com.oracle.cie.domain.template.dependency.UndeterministicSelectionException: One of the following needs to be selected:
          A - 11.1.1.0 [som]
          A - 11.1.1.0 [som]One of the following needs to be selected:
          B - 11.1.1.0 [som]
          B - 11.1.1.0 [som]One of the following needs to be selected:
          C - 11.1.1.0 [som]
          C - 11.1.1.0 [som]
        at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.CommandExceptionHandler.handleException(CommandExceptionHandler.java:51)
        at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLScriptContext.handleException(WLScriptContext.java:1538)
        at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLScriptContext.addTemplate(WLScriptContext.java:420)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

Why am I getting 2 duplicate names? Have I missed any configuration? How to fix this issue?